# SQL SERVER How to take each group by as an alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count all of the column in my table that has value >= 10.
here is my table :

> ```sql
> Date#####   |  Value1 |  Value2 |   Value3 | Type
>  23/04/2014  |  1,2    |    12,3 |    10    | Alert
>  23/04/2014  |  11,2   |    3    |   10,3   | Alert
>  24/04/2014  |  10,9   |    3    |     1    | Non-Alert
> ```

I want to take each group by on column type as an alias, for example : GROUP BY Type = 'Alert' as TAlert, Group BY Type='Non-Alert as TNon-Alert'.

Assume that I have a lot of group of date, I want it to display only the last 3 group of date.

Here is my code so far:

```sql
select d, cnt
from (
    select top 3 [Date] as d,
           sum(  Case When value1 >= 10 then 1 else 0 end
               + Case When Value2 >= 10 then 1 else 0 end
              ) as cnt
    from tbBooth
    GROUP BY [Date],[Type]
    Order By [Date] DESC
) x
ORDER BY d ASC
```

Is there anyway how to do it? because I want to put it on my line chart series, TAlert in series1 and TNon-Alert in series2.
Here is the result of the query in my table,

> >
>        d for date,,, cnt for counting
>
> ```sql
>  d           | Type       | cnt
>  23/04/2014  | Non-Alert  | 8
>  24/04/2014  | Alert      | 3
>  24/04/2014  | Non-Alert  | 7
> ```

then, I want to take each group in column type. for example group of Alert as TAlert, or group of Non-Alert as TNon-Alert....

Thanks in advances....

Comment: Why don't you simply put in `WHERE Type = 'Alert'`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Looks like you need to PIVOT the data. Could you edit the post to include the desired output and some sample data?

Comment: What's with the commas in the different `Value` columns?  Are they not integer (or some other numeric type)?

Comment: @TomasPastircak I cant use where because it will only take one of the group. I want to take both separately. and I dont know how to use two query into a chart on my program. please guide me if you know how to do that.

Comment: @user3567963 Can you please also add what is the result that you get from your script? Are there only 3 columns from which you want to get the values?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse they are decimal type...

Comment: @TomasPastircak yes they are.... I have a lot of data.. and it only,, I am sorry,,, I change the code a bit,, on the group by,, it become group by[Date],[Type]......

Comment: ...okay, and the comma is the decimal separator (I was worried it was a multi-valued column, which would have made this difficult).  What do you want your final output from SQL to look like?  It sounds like you still had processing to do after the current output example.  Is it that you want the last three dates, with both `Alert` and `Non-Alert` types?  If so, what should happen in the event that one of the types skips a day - they get a `0` count?

Comment: @user3567963 I mean, I think that the query you are providing should return what you are saying is the expected result... so I'm asking what is the actual result of the query

Comment: Is it MySql or SQL Server? It has both tags.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse it might be one of them or it might be both... it depends on the user... and it think it won't be null because I set the value for column type automatically generated when the user choose something.....

Comment: @dean I created a program using VB.net and SQL SERVER as a database,, but I also tag mysql because I think mysql expert can help me to solve my problem as well...

Comment: You shouldn't have, it's confusing. It's different product, different syntax, consider removing the mysql tag.

Comment: @dean I'm really sorry,, I didn't mean to make everyone confuse.. and I think my query is wrong, it's display the last 3 record but not the group of date because I already make 2 kind of group by so the group of date already separated....

Comment: OK, check my answer, let's work from there if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to UNPIVOT it first, then SUM with the CASE. I'm not sure where the "only the last 3 group of date" fits in, maybe a more complete sample data would help.

But, with what we have now, try this:

```
;with x as (
    select *
    from (
        select [date], [type], Value1, Value2, Value3
        from tbBooth
    ) p
    unpivot (
        v for val in (Value1, Value2, Value3)
    ) as up
)
select [date], [type], sum(case when v >= 10 then 1 else 0 end)
from x
group by [date], [type]
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me.... I will try your code and make some modification in my query...